# SharePoint 2013. why Anonymous user Identity need to be 'IUSR'?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, iis, anonymous-authentication

Environment: SharePoint 2013, IIS 8.

No images and CSS displayed in the Central Admin.

In firebug, its authentication failure.

I checked in the IIS, the **Anonymous user Identity** was set to **'Application Pool Identity'**.

I changed it to '**IUSR**' and now it is working fine.

***Why Anonymous user Identity need to be 'IUSR' ? Is there any MSDN/KB article ?***

Complete trouble shooting is explained in this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/105103/13391),

Answer (score 1):

> This built-in account does not need a password and will be the default
> identity that is used when anonymous authentication is enabled. If you
> look in the applicationHost.config file you will see the following
> definition:

```
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" defaultLogonDomain="" />
```

> This tells IIS to use the new built-in account for all anonymous
> authentication requests. The biggest advantages are that you can:
>
> •Set file system permissions for the IUSR account by using Windows
> Explorer or any of the many command line tools.
>
> •No longer need to worry about passwords expiring for this account.
>
> •Use xcopy /o to copy files along with their ownership and ACL information to different
> computers seamlessly.

looks like your code changed it to app pool account identity which i presume was for maintanance? which is an old method, this account in iis7 replaces it as confirmed here:

> The IIS_IUSRS group replaces the IIS_WPG group. This built-in group
> has access to all the necessary file and system resources so that an
> account, when added to this group, can seamlessly act as an
> application pool identity.

and

> IIS 7 and above also makes the process of configuring an application
> pool identity and making all necessary changes easier. **When IIS starts
> a worker process, it needs to create a token that the process will
> use. When this token is created, IIS automatically adds the IIS_IUSRS
> membership to the worker processes token at runtime. The accounts that
> run as 'application pool identities' no longer need to be an explicit
> part of the IIS_IUSRS group**. This change helps you to set up your
> systems with fewer obstacles and makes your overall experience more
> favorable.

a very indepth and detailed explanation here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis