# SharePoint central admin not showing correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I got the central admin not showing properly even I don't change anything. I did IIS restart and token recycle in IIS.
[image]

Comment: Can you check if somebody has changed permission on the CA web application (IIS), also, see if network service account has enough access on style related files. I am thinking this as an issue with permission.

Comment: The styles are not loaded properly

Comment: How should I check styles for it. I am very new in sharepoint.

Comment: You can use Firebug in Firefox or IE Developer Tool [F 12] and check the status of css requests

Answer (score 0):

could be related to access issue to the hive files, where the user doesnt have right access:

check this out:

[SharePoint 2013. why Anonymous user Identity need to be 'IUSR'?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/106151/sharepoint-2013-why-anonymous-user-identity-need-to-be-iusr)

and

[SharePoint 404 not found after IIS hardening](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105103/sharepoint-404-not-found-after-iis-hardening)